# Mapbox gl expression to get match in text field

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to set one of the values from feature properties to text-field depending on a property

```
"text-field": [
                "match",
                ["get","label"],
                "L1","{name}",
                "{label}"
            ]
```

But it displays {label} or {name}, also try the same in maputnik.

The expression works fine for text-color and other icon-image property but there I am using hard-coded values after 'get' in setting icon-image like

```
"match",
["get","label"],
    "L1","house",
    "marker"
```

Is it possible to set values in expression with variable value? If Yes what am I doing wrong?

Or the support is only for hard-coded values?

Answer (score 1):

'get' is used to access values in the expression like label,so you can

"text-field": [
                "match",
                ["get","label"],
                "L1",["get","name"],
                ["get","label"]
            ]

reference:https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/mapbox-gl-js-expressions/